# Idea on where to keep terminated contracts

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this database here for a project im doing. For a small company. It is mainly for contracts for software distribution. The contracts will go into the contracts table obviously, my boss also wants to know if and when and who terminates a contract at any time. Also who terminates the contract once it has expired.

**My current DB**
[image]

I have two ideas but my inexperience brain thinks that something is totally wrong or off.

First: inserting fields in the contract table terminatedate,terminatereason,terminator. And initalize is as NULL as long as the contract is still active.

But i feel this is wrong (LOL) and the one that can terminate the contract are from the users, would it be redundant if since there already a FK user_id referencing who created the contract.

Second: Creating another table Terminate with terminateid,terminatedate,terminatereason,and FK from users as the terminator.

and terminateid will be in the contract table as FK. and for active contracts this FK will be NULL. Will this work?

due give comments and criticism. Im a student in training rn. Thnx a bunch :)

Comment: I would simply add an active record and inactive_reason to the Contract table. If active = 0, then fill the reason_inactive. But there are so many possibilities here, also a matter of taste.

Comment: thnx @an33sh for the suggested edit. I cant put pics directly cuz im new to the site.

Comment: @SQL_M i get ur idea, but the problem with user who create and user who terminates (who could be different) still what holds me back.

Comment: Do you only need to store when a contract was opened and closed? Can a contract be reopened? If yes, then you need a "history table".  If not and open/close are the only changes you need to register then I would go for an easy solution: in the contract table add a foreign key to the user (terminator), a reason and date. Do you need a status field? If you only have open/close status you don't need an extra column since you can deduct the status, but if you have more, than would be better to have a column.

Comment: It can't be reopened so I guess no history table. Ill use your suggestion using add terminator, reason & date. Thnx @Mark . I have one little question, is it a good idea to rename foreign keys? Because the long name it has after linking is kinda tedious while coding php.